# Fit a Quadratic Curve to Data

Tags: quadratics, regression

I have some data and I want to fit a quadratic curve for my data But I don't know that how to it do? 
My data :

$x,y = 100,45;$
 
$x_1,y_1= 101, 50$;
$x_2,y_3=99,35$;
$\ldots$

For instance this website is fitting function very well http://mycurvefit.com/
But I don't know how ıt is work?What is the background?

How can I calculate mathematical way this function?
Thank your advanced

Comment: You have 3 data points, interpolate them

Comment: If you just want the curve you can plot the points in Excel (Scatter plot option) then fit a quadratic trend line (right click a point, add trendline and choose the quadratic option). This approximation is based on the least squares method.

Comment: Actually I dont use exel I am writing in c but ı dont know how ı can fit a quadratic curve so I have asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to fit your given points with the curve $
f(x) = a + b\,x + c\,x^{\,2} $. There are many "fitting" methods to choose from depending on considering the nature of the data and of the underlying error. I suppose you refer to the most common "least square" method (in the most common acception which assumes that the error is just on the $y$ coordinate).
Then the underlying mechanism of it is to calculate the total square error $$
E(a,b,c)^{\,2}  = \sum\limits_k {\left( {y_{\,k}  - f(x_{\,k} )} \right)^{\,2} }  = \sum\limits_k {\left( {y_{\,k}  - a - b\,x_{\,k}  - c\,x_{\,k} ^{\,2} } \right)^{\,2} } 
$$
which depends on the unknown parameters $a,b,c$ and find for which value of them it becomes minimum. So (under proper assumptions concerning the data distribution ...which practically are assessed from a plot of the data) you are to solve the system
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 = {\partial  \over {\partial \,a}}E(a,b,c)^{\,2}  =  - 2\sum\limits_k {\left( {y_{\,k}  - a - b\,x_{\,k}  - c\,x_{\,k} ^{\,2} } \right)}  \hfill \cr 
  0 = {\partial  \over {\partial \,b}}E(a,b,c)^{\,2}  =  - 2\sum\limits_k {x_{\,k} \left( {y_{\,k}  - a - b\,x_{\,k}  - c\,x_{\,k} ^{\,2} } \right)}  \hfill \cr 
  0 = {\partial  \over {\partial \,c}}E(a,b,c)^{\,2}  =  - 2\sum\limits_k {x_{\,k} ^{\,2} \left( {y_{\,k}  - a - b\,x_{\,k}  - c\,x_{\,k} ^{\,2} } \right)}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
This is finally a linear system in the unknowns $a,b,c$ which provides the solution, always given that the data distribution be actually "nearly quadratic".

Comment: What I mean is that If I use this method I will achieve  my goal THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: @j.doe you are welcome

Comment: @G Cab before asking my question as a separate entry, I want to know if I am asking for the right direction. I am given a model (curve equation). And I had collected a set of data running experiments. I have some basic knowledge of linear least square fitting, non-linear least square fitting and derivatives. I fitted data to a curve, and derived an equation. But that's so different from the given model. What I really want is to figure out how to fit my data into this given model. I know I sound `scattered`. Care to guide please?

Comment: @bonCodigo Data fitting is a complex subject, just some guidelines. a)*Experimental data*: usual LS method assume the $x$ are known precisely and the error is only in the $y$ (or reverse). If both are prone to errors, the approach is more sophisticated. b)*Model* is understood to be a *family* of curves, defined by some parameters to be adjusted to the data: which (how many) parameters and their admissible range make the results much different.

Comment: @GCab yes experimental data and Y is derived from it. And 4 parameters of X is also provided as initial values. These initial values are familiar values derived from another experiment where expected curve was fitted well. When I apply (hand calculations) simple limits like certain parameter is infinity or 0, the values produced by curve for Y is not matching. I am using R for fitting. Is it possible to have a chat with you? Is the blackboard (chatroom app) still available here on math.exchange?

Comment: @bonCodigo: unfortunately I am not familiar with the chatroom here. But I think you can post your question (and in case drop a comment to let me know about). From the little I can grasp from your comment, you are facing a "classical" situation in which the model is not suitable to represent the data (the parameters  found are *strange* and very *unstable*!).

Comment: @GCab I did create a chat room and invited you. Perhaps you didn't receive it. So I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2269407/46277), but I am trying to figure out what datasets I need to share.