# least square fitting to a non-linear curve

Tags: limits, curves, least-squares, simulation

The model is already proved to be correct for a previous simulation. 
Trying to apply the same for a new set of data. 
There are few constants, couple parameters with X. Both X and Y are derived from valid experiments. These parameters are what I want to fit, predict, simulate.

I wrote a code in R to fit the values to this model by providing initials values from the previous simulation. The curve shape comes right. However when applied simple limits to the equations, e.g. lim-> infinity, lim->0, then the value for Y doesn't match the actual.

I do have basic derivatives knowledge and understand somewhat what least square fitting is trying to achieve. But I am not sure the whole chunk that I am missing in order to connect the dots, to simplify for a better solution.

Following is the equation:

**$$y = p2 +\frac{p2-p1}{(1 + \frac{exp(cons1*p3*exp(cons2*p4*x^2))}{x})}$$**

Data sets: blob = exponential functions

if limits of blob become really large, $$y = P2$$
if blob becomes 0, $$y = \frac{p2 + P1}{2}$$

Comment: @GCab so I attempted to put the question into some words. Does it make sense?

Comment: First, your equation  $$y = p2 +\frac{p2-p1}{(1 + \frac{exp(cons1*p3*exp(cons2*p4*x^2)}{x})}$$ isn't correct, fix the brackets. Second, what are the adjustable parameters among cons1, cons2, p1, p2, p3, p4 ? Third, we can't say what goes wrong in your calculus without at least two numerical examples : a data set leading to good result and a data set leading to wrong result. No need to publish your code in R.

Comment: @JJacquelin I really need to thank you. I corrected the bracket here. And then today I looked at the brackets in my programme. I had a bracket in the wrong place and which had screwed up my model. Once it was done, data fits with an acceptable fit.

Comment: So, *JJacquelin* already gave you suitable indications, and seems to understand that then you solved your problem: good